# Java calculating percentage difference between to longs

Tags: java, math, double, long-integer

I need to compare the run time of 2 programs. I capture the elapsed time of each program using `System.nanoTime()`. One program returns with a time of 1449870040074994000 nano seconds, the other with a time of 1449870040080970000 nano seconds.

I am using `double percent = ((big-small)/big)*100;` but this is returning 0.0. Is this because double can't represent such a small number?

What am I doing wrong and how can I calculate this correctly?

Note that I need to make a conclusion along the lines of "Program A is on average x% faster than Program B"

Thanks!

Comment: Try `double percent = (big - small) * 100.0 / big;` as `double` can represent such a small number however `long` cannot represent any value between 0 and 1.

Comment: Also, to get uptime of program `ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean().getUptime()`